# Corrupt Raspberry Pi Zero W Micro SD Card

Tags: sd-card

I was working on my Raspberry Pi until suddenly the power cable powering it came out of the port. I attempted to reboot my Raspberry Pi but it refuses to boot. I plugged the Micro SD card into my computer and Windows Explorer crashed. Is there any way to get my Micro SD card working again? I'm fine with losing all of my data on it, but now it's not even functioning. I can't even format it because every time I plug it in Windows Explorer crashes.

Comment: do you have any linux machine ?

Comment: if not- any solution that can format card- as digital camera, android phone, with a less complicated operating system to enhace formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I plugged it into my Windows Phone which didn't work, it only managed to format the first partition but still left the second partition corrupt and still crashed Windows Explorer upon plugging it into my computer. I plugged it into my friends Mac running OS X which detected that the Micro SD Card had two partitions. I then proceeded to use OS X's disc utility to format both partitions and return my Micro SD Card back into its initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use a "dumb" device like a camera, that asks no questions of the card and simply formats it. Phones are too clever these days (though Guy D above is essentially correct)